# Odd Behavior of UNION Subquery, why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, navicat

The following two queries return the same information; however, **the first takes 1.1 seconds** to complete and **the second takes 0.06 seconds**.

This table has **198,810 records** and `"Contacts"."ReqID"` is indexed.

1. Why am I seeing such a performance hit with the (seemingly) less complex query?
2. Why would the UNION subquery speed up the process?

****Edit****

I have ran both queries in rapid succession and see no change in performance.

---

### Query 1

```
SELECT
    "Contacts"."ContactID",
    "Contacts"."ReqID"
FROM
    "Contacts"
WHERE
    "Contacts"."ReqID" = 2426;
```

****EDIT****

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Index Scan using "Contacts_ReqID_idx" on "Contacts"  (cost=0.00..30.08 rows=11 width=78) (actual time=0.076..0.115 rows=14 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ("ReqID" = 2426)
Total runtime: 0.159 ms
```

**1.1 seconds** to return **14 records**.

---

### Query 2

```
SELECT
    "T1"."ContactID",
    "T1"."ReqID"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            "Contacts"."ContactID",
            "Contacts"."ReqID"
        FROM
            "Contacts"
        WHERE
            "Contacts"."ReqID" = 2426
        UNION
        SELECT
            "Contacts"."ContactID",
            "Contacts"."ReqID"
        FROM
            "Contacts"
        WHERE
            "Contacts"."ReqID" = 2426
    ) AS "T1"
ORDER BY
    "ReqID"
```

****EDIT****

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Sort (cost=61.74..61.80 rows=22 width=100) (actual time=0.313..0.329 rows=14 loops=1)
  Sort Key: "Contacts"."ReqID"
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=60.81..61.03 rows=22 width=78) (actual time=0.266..0.285 rows=14 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..60.37 rows=22 width=78) (actual time=0.063..0.201 rows=28 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using "Contacts_ReqID_idx" on "Contacts"  (cost=0.00..30.08 rows=11 width=78) (actual time=0.059..0.106 rows=14 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ("ReqID" = 2426)
              ->  Index Scan using "Contacts_ReqID_idx" on "Contacts"  (cost=0.00..30.08 rows=11 width=78) (actual time=0.006..0.024 rows=14 loops=1)
                Index Cond: ("ReqID" = 2426)
Total runtime: 0.410 ms
```

**0.06 seconds** to return **14 records**.

Comment: What happens if you run your "test" in the opposite order?

Comment: I don't understand your question... I think you mean, if I run Query 2 first, and then Query 1, does it change the speed of Query 1. If so, then there is no change (still about 1.1 seconds).

Comment: Can you `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` both queries?

Comment: + Try to run them several times (to enable caching) before getting the statistics.

Comment: Yes, query 1 can affect the speed of query 2. By pulling in pages from disk. Also: please add your tuning parameters to the question. (I suspect you run postgres with the default settings)

Comment: Yes, I am running the default postgres settings.

Comment: `Total runtime: 0.159 ms` and  `Total runtime: 0.410 ms` How did you get the 1.1 and 0.06 sec measurements?

Comment: I use Navicat and it reports the time elapsed in the bottom right hand corner. Additionally, there is a noticeable lag in the first query compared to the second.

Comment: I don't know what navicat is, but it does influence your result in some way. (maybe it sets up a connection first?)  Eliminate the middle man: work from the psql prompt, or use pgadmin3.

Comment: wow, PgAdmin shows very different numbers 5.500 ms for Query 1 and 7.118 ms for Query 2.

Comment: If performance matters, default settings of most distributions are way too minimalistic. [To get you started ..](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

Comment: Changing the default setting of Postgres is the area that I feel the least educated in. I started reading Postgres 9.0 High Performance, but I am still not ready to change anything. Other then the link you sent, do you have any other advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Navicat (the software I use to access and administrate my database) is running some extra code that allows in place editing of the data when running a simple `SELECT * FROM [Table]` statement. Below is the email I received from a support representative.

---

> Dear [Navicat User],
>
> Thanks for your email. Please note that in order to get column
>   information and allow update data afterwards, Navicat will run extra
>   SQL when the query is a simple SELECT query. Using UNION, Navicat not
>   allows user update any data in the query result.
>
> ...
>
> Sincerely,
>  Mayho Ho
>  Navicat Support Center